# Adobe Edge and dynamic images

Tags: image, dynamic, adobe-edge

Is it possible to use Adobe Edge and have, say the background a dynamic image pulled up from my mysql database? I was thinking of something like below somehow.

I can't find a way to, or anything related on internet searches, so if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

```
<?php echo $row_rsTable['tablePicture1']; ?> OR MAYBE THIS

<img class="picture" src="<?php echo $row_rsTable['tablePicture1']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're finished with your site in edge, you can always open up the html, css, and javascript files in your favorite text editor to make changes afterwards.

So for instance, you could animate an image in edge, then just go in afterwards and change the src to whatever image you like, dynamic or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your file name/path from database without breaking auto-generated html/js architecture from Edge, you could use for that purpose simple, php REST Api.

Just make simple REST service which returns the name/path of desired image file in JSON format, and parse it with jQuery $.post() anywhere in your Edge app.

-

You could also do it by changing your main Edge app html file to .php extension and read data from webserwer's database in the 'traditional' way. Then assign that data to global javascript variable, and then use that variable anywhere in your Edge app.